# definition of exterior algebra and multiplication

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

According to 'an introduction to manifolds' written by Tu, he defined the exterior algebra as
\begin{equation}
A_*(V)=\oplus^\infty_{k=0}A_k(V)
\end{equation}
where $V$ is a vectorspace with dimension $n$ and $A_k(V)$ is a set of alternating $k$tensors.

here I have a question. The book said that multiplication in this algebra is the wedge product.

But if $a^i\in A_{k_i}(V),b^j\in A_{l_j}(V)$ then
\begin{equation}
a=(a^1,... a^{k'})\oplus^\infty_{k=0}A_k(V),(b^1,... b^l)\in\oplus^\infty_{k=0}A_k(V)
\end{equation}
Then I don't know how to multiply these $a$ and $b$ through wedge product.

Comment: You know how to multiply $a^i$ by $b^j$; extend by bilinearity of the wedge product.

Comment: I guess that your intention is that $(a^1\wedge b^1, ... a^{k'}\wedge b^{k'},...)$. But it is awkward for me. Can you show me how to denote the wedge product?

Comment: It's easier to understand if you write $a$ as $a = \sum_{k\ge 0} a^k$ (where all but finitely many of the $a^k$ are $0$, and similarly for $b$. Then $$ a\wedge b = \left( \sum_{k\ge 0} a^k \right) \wedge \left( \sum_{\ell\ge 0} b^\ell \right) = \sum_{k,\ell \ge 0} a^k\wedge b^\ell, $$ because otherwise $\wedge$ wouldn't be blinear.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!. I understand this concept directly.